# Xcode/Swift Constraint

Tags: swift

When I run the program, all looks good until I rotate the screen.  The views move into the correct places with the correct sizes (I think) but I get the below error message.  Whether I begin in portrait or landscape, the problem arises at the transition.  There is more than enough room in both portrait and landscape modes.

There are four `UIView`s on the `UIViewController` - none has any hardwired constraints.  In Portrait mode (narrow), the views are stacked `v1` on top, then `v2`, `v3`, and `v4` on the bottom.   In wide mode (landscape), `v1` and `v2` are stacked on the right, `v3` and `v4` stacked on the left.  `v2`'s height will vary to fill the screen.

I am using the iPhone 12 Pro Max (15.4) Simulator - screen dimensions are w=428.0, h=926.0.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class VC3: UIViewController {
            
    // MARK: Views
    @IBOutlet weak var v1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var v2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var v3: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var v4: UIView!
            
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setConstraints()
    }
               
    
    // MARK: CONSTRAINTS -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // arrays of constraints:
    var commonConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []  // common to all layouts
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []  // "narrow" layout
    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []    // "wide" layout
        
    
    func setConstraints() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(commonConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
        
        v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // get screen size
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        debugPrint("screen size: w=\(screenWidth), h=\(screenHeight)")

        
        let g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        //debugPrint("g = \(g)")
        
        let v1h: CGFloat = 90
        let v3h: CGFloat = 182
        let v4h: CGFloat = 156
        let padding: CGFloat = 4
        
        
        commonConstraints = [
            // set the fixed heights
            v1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: v1h),
            // v2 height will vary, taking up remaining space on sccreen
            v3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: v3h),
            v4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: v4h),
       ]
        
        
        narrowConstraints = [
            v1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            v1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.topAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.topAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.topAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
        ]
        
        wideConstraints = [
            //v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.widthAnchor, constant: padding)
            //v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.widthAnchor, constant: padding)
            v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.widthAnchor),
            v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.widthAnchor),
            
            v1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            v1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.topAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            v3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.leadingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            
            v4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            v4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.leadingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            v4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
        ]
            
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(commonConstraints)
        activateConstraintsFor(view.frame.size)           
    }
    
    
    func activateConstraintsFor(_ size: CGSize) {
        // Wide:
        if size.width > size.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        // Narrow:
        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }
            
    
    // MARK:  TRANSITION -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        //debugPrint("VC3: viewWillTransition")
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            
            //debugPrint("VC3: viewWillTransition")
            self.activateConstraintsFor(size)
            
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // do something after the transition
            // debugPrint("VCDSGraphs: viewWillTransition (after transition")
        })
    }

}
```

Error message:

```
2022-03-21 10:40:47.784690-0600 Constraints[30588:3648155] [HardwareKeyboard] -[UIApplication getKeyboardDevicePropertiesForSenderID:shouldUpdate:usingSyntheticEvent:], failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358211) use primary keyboard info instead.
2022-03-21 10:40:47.790570-0600 Constraints[30588:3648155] [HardwareKeyboard] -[UIApplication getKeyboardDevicePropertiesForSenderID:shouldUpdate:usingSyntheticEvent:], failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358211) use primary keyboard info instead.
2022-03-21 10:40:48.005009-0600 Constraints[30588:3648155] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cda40 UIView:0x15a7065d0.height == 90   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cda90 UIView:0x15a706dd0.height == 182   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cdae0 UIView:0x15a706f40.height == 156   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cdb80 UIView:0x15a7065d0.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600002cfc540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cdc20 UIView:0x15a7065d0.bottom == UIView:0x15a706c60.top - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cdd10 UIView:0x15a706c60.bottom == UIView:0x15a706dd0.top - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cde00 UIView:0x15a706dd0.bottom == UIView:0x15a706f40.top - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cdef0 UIView:0x15a706f40.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x600002cfc540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom - 4   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036e35c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x15a7070b0.height == 428   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cd810 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600002cfc540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(21)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15a7070b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cd770 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002cfc540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x15a7070b0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036cda90 UIView:0x15a706dd0.height == 182   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

### Edit

The error messages only happen when transitioning from portrait to landscape.

### Update

The error occurs if the sum of heights of `v3` and `v4` is greater than 297.  But the screen height is 428, so what constraint is getting violated?

Comment: You'd have a lot easier time debugging this if you gave your constraints names (identifiers).

Comment: I hope you get an answer for this question - I often get the same error when using SwiftUI, which shouldn't have constraint issues, because you barely define constraints that can be conflicting.

Comment: don't you need to update the constraints and then animateAlongside a "layout if needed"?

Comment: @matt: unfortunately, that is not helping me here, but thank you for the tip - I will use it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

the `wideConstraints` dont seem to be set up properly, they are pinned to some of the wrong things.
something like this is "more" correct, but also may conflict with your height constraints in `commonConstraints`.

```
wideConstraints = [
            v1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            v1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            v1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            v1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v2.topAnchor),
            
            v2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.bottomAnchor),
            v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            v2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            v2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            v3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            v3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            v3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            v3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v4.topAnchor),
            
            v4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v3.topAnchor),
            v4.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            v4.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            v4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        ]
```

Comment: this does not give me the layout I want. `v3` does not appear at all in landscape mode.